# Prevent CSS Fade when Changing Layout

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

So I have a div with a basic CSS opacity setting on it:

```
.fade {
    opacity: 1;
}

<div class="menu">
    <div class="fade">Text</div>
</div>
```

Where it gets tricky is that for large screen sizes this div is meant to always be visible, but on smaller ones it is meant to be hidden and then fade in/out when a button is clicked.

```
<div class="menu toggled">
    <div class="fade">Text</div>
</div>

@media(max-width:767px) {
    .fade {
        -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease 0s;
        transition: opacity 0.5s ease 0s;
        opacity: 0;
    }

    .toggled .fade {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

The problem I'm running into (and I realize it's pretty nitpicky) is that when I resize the window, crossing the threshold to the smaller screen size causes the element to jump to its new position and then fade out.  This looks weird.  I just want the div to become immediately invisible when it snaps to its new position.  Is there a way I can do that without breaking the fade in/out transform for my toggle button on the smaller screen size?

I've come up with some solutions to prevent the fade during the resize, but so far they all break the fade out animation when using the toggle.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE 1:**

Thanks @Chris James Champeaux for the answer!  I've modified it slightly to fit my needs:

```
$(".menu").each(function ()
{
    if ($(this).hasClass("toggled"))
    {
        $(this).removeClass("toggled");
        $(this).children(".fade").each(function ()
        {
            $opacity = $(this).css("opacity");
            $(this).stop(true).animate({ "opacity": "0" }, 500 * $opacity, function ()
            {
                $(this).css("opacity", "");
            });
        });
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).addClass("toggled");
        $(this).children(".fade").each(function ()
        {
            $opacity = $(this).css("opacity");
            $(this).stop(true).animate({ "opacity": "1" }, 500 * (1 - $opacity));
        });
    }
});
```

The callback to clear the inline opacity style after the fade out was necessary in order to relinquish control back to the stylesheet (otherwise the element would remain hidden when transitioning back to the larger screen size).

The stop() call and interpolated duration were optional and just make it so that the animation reverses smoothly if the user presses the button again before the fade is complete.

Anyway, problem solved.  :)  Thanks again Chris!

**UPDATE 2:**

Also just to clarify for anyone who comes across this later... using this solution you also would remove the opacity animation from the stylesheet, leaving it like this:

```
.fade {
    opacity: 1;
}

@media(max-width:767px) {
    .fade {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could animate the fade with an on click within jquery, probably also with javascript.

```
$(".toggle").click(function () {
    if ($(".fade").css("opacity") > 0) {
        $(".fade).animate({"opacity": "0"}, 500);
    } else {
        $(".fade).animate({"opacity": "1"}, 500);
    }
});
```

I did not test this but it should work

Comment: Thanks!  That worked - I had to add a callback to remove the inline style jquery added for the opacity once the fade out was complete but otherwise this did the trick!